# Setting up Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to set up Flask and SQLAlchemy on Windows but I've been running into issues.

I've been using Flask-SQLAlchemy along with PostgreSQL 9.1.4 (32 bit) and the Psycopg2 package. Here are the relevant bits of code, I created a basic User model just to test that my DB is connecting, and committing.

The three bits of code would come from the `__init__.py` file of my application, the `models.py` file and my `settings.py` file.

When I try opening up my interactive prompt and try the code in the following link out I get a ProgrammingError exception (details in link).

What could be causing this? I followed the documentation and I'm simply confused as to what I'm doing wrong especially considering that I've also used Django with psycopg2 and PostgreSQL on Windows.

Comment: It seems the schema is not created. You need to create the db first, and assign the login to the db in postgresql; then you should be able to create the tables.

Answer (score 6):

I had great help using this tutorial [Flask Mega Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Answer (score 4):

At the time you execute `create_all`, `models.py` has never been imported, so no class is declared. Thus, `create_all` does not create any table.

To solve this problem, import `models` before running `create_all` or, even better, don't separate the `db` object from the model declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps to use Flask SQLAlchemy:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

//employee.db database will get created in current python project

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///employee.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Employee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    dept = db.Column(db.String(40))
```

To test this code you need to run your python shell

> RUN IN PYTHON SHELL :

```
//This is going to create table create_all() method
from one_to_many import db
db.create_all()

//This is going to insert data into table
from one_to_many import Employee
new_emp = Employee(name="Viraj",dept="IT")
db.session.add(new_emp)
db.session.commit()

//To check or retrieve data use this 
show_all_data = Employee.query.all()
for i in show_all_data:
    print(i.id,i.name,i.dept)
```